# Как заставить скрипт искать не по тексту, а по select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как заставить скрипт искать не по тексту, а по select?

Код:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.tableSearch = function(options){
        if(!$(this).is('table')){
            return;
        }
        var tableObj = $(this),
            searchText = (options.searchText)?options.searchText:'Search: ',
            searchPlaceHolder = (options.searchPlaceHolder)?options.searchPlaceHolder:'',
            divObj = $('<div style="float:right;">'+searchText+'</div><br /><br />'),
            inputObj = $('<input type="text" placeholder="'+searchPlaceHolder+'" />'),
            caseSensitive = (options.caseSensitive===true)?true:false,
            searchFieldVal = '',
            pattern = '';
        inputObj.off('keyup').on('keyup', function(){
            searchFieldVal = $(this).val();
            pattern = (caseSensitive)?RegExp(searchFieldVal):RegExp(searchFieldVal, 'i');
            tableObj.find('tbody tr').hide().each(function(){
                var currentRow = $(this);
                currentRow.find('td').each(function(){
                    if(pattern.test($(this).html())){
                        currentRow.show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        tableObj.before(divObj.append(inputObj));
        return tableObj;
    }
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function(){$('table.search-table').tableSearch({searchText:'Поиск',search:'Напишите название'});});
```

Comment: А где тут select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, в вашем случае вам поможет Typeahead. Это готовое решение на поиск из существующих значений с выпадающей подсказкой.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как ее сюда подключить https://igroteka.club/Tablica2/sample-table.html

Comment: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/    это ответ на вопрос как подключить.

Comment: Например я вставляю эти строки с примера 
<Default Suggestions>

И ничего не работает. я просто в этом нифига не понимаю если честно так что извините за тупые вопросы

Comment: Вот страничка куда питаюсь его впихнуть https://igroteka.club/Tablica2/sample-table.html

Comment: Самый простой вариант: Значения нужной колонки впихнуть в массив JS, который потом будет использоваться для поиска. В basic примере это реализовано. И будет вам счастье.

Comment: В общем кто поможет или проще сказать сделает все заплачу 200р
Пишите на почту kasper.php@gmail.com